# Sticky Elastic IP on AWS EC2

Tags: linux, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, ubuntu-16.04

A specific 'Elastic IP' is always associated with the EC2 instance launched from one of my custom AWS AMI.

```
ubuntu@ip-:~$ sudo ip addr show lo
inet 157.XX.XX.235/32 scope global lo
```

It is also persistent across server restarts. Can't find any configuration for the elastic IP in /etc/network/interfaces.

Is this setting coming from EC2 instance metadata and cloud-init? Couldn't find anything in /var/log/ as well. There is no user supplied user_data.

Answer (score 0):

Elastic IP addresses exist within the VPC networking layer and are used by Internet Gateways.

When traffic enters a VPC with an Elastic IP address as the destination, the Internet Gateway performs a **reverse NAT** and translates the public IP address into a **private IP address** within the VPC. The EC2 instance receives the request on its public IP.

When traffic sent from an instance with an Elastic IP, the traffic comes 'from' the private IP address, but it is translated into the public IP address when it goes through the Internet Gateway.

So, an Amazon EC2 instance is never actually aware of its public IP address. It only sees traffic via its private IP address. This has the benefit that the Elastic IP address can be **reassociated** with another EC2 instance and no configuration changes are required on the old or new instances. It's magic!

I'm not familiar with the command you are using. When I run it on an Amazon Linux instance that has an Elastic IP address, the command does *not* show the public IP address of the instance. Perhaps this is different on Ubuntu, so somebody has configured it somewhere on the instance (which they should not do, since it could change through reassociation).

Comment: I understand that I don't need to configure the Public IP on the network interface. 

I'm unable to trace where this setting is coming from. Normally it is set from /etc/network/interfaces. There is nothing in there. This is my problem.

Comment: It is available from `curl http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/public-ipv4/`, but I'm not sure how it gets into the `ip` command.